# Groovy: How to get Type on which a static method is called?

Tags: groovy, static-methods

When a static method defined on Base class is called using Child class, How to find it was called on Child class type?:

```
class Base {
    static def method(){
        println "class on which this method is called? ${this}"
    }
}

class Child extends Base {}

Child.method()
```

In the code above, `this` rightly points to the Base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with actual static methods, but a nice alternative is to use the groovy *expandoMetaClass* to add  a static closure method. Inside said closure, you can access the calling class as *delegate*. I.e.

```
Base.metaClass.static.anotherMethod = {
   println "class on which another method is called? ${delegate}"
}
```

Calling now Base.anotherMethod() will have *delegate* referring to Base and calling  Child.anotherMethod will have it pointing to Child.